# How can I build 2 docker images with their IP address in environment file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-build

I have two services, front-server and core-server. These services can be deployed in difference machines.

In each service, I store the IP address of other.

In **.env** of **front-server**, I have `CORE_ADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

In **.env** of **core-server**, I have `FRONT_ADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

The problem is, at the time I build the image for each service, I still don't know IP of images. I only know the IP address after running image.

So, I want to ask if there are any solution to config the environment of 2 docker images instead of storing IP address of other service in environment file.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you set up a DNS server, so you're not dependent on fixed IP addresses here?  If these parts are only being used inside containers (front-server doesn't provide a browser-based application) can you use the DNS system provided by Docker itself?  Or run can you both parts behind a reverse proxy so that you can use a path-only URL without needing to know the network environment?

Comment: If you don't know the IP address when you build the Docker image why are you attempting to embed the IP address when you build the Docker image? In other words, you are using the wrong solution for your problem. You seem to have a vague recognition that your solution is wrong. Have you considered using a mechanism where each service publishes how to connect to it?